# Can I escape "automatically turn URLs/Emails into links"?

Tags: entry

I would like this option for the "body" field of an entry, but for another field where I want to take a web address and eventually generate a button link, I don't want it encoded, or of course the button ends up messed up. Any ideas/solutions to this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you mean encode or not on a case by case basis within the same fieldtype?

Comment: Hi Jean, I  have a field group that has a "body" field (wygwam) to automatically turn URLs/Emails into links, but another field, "link" (textarea) I don't want that to happen because I insert that into an HTML button as the href. I'd like to allow the "body" field to automatically turn URLs/Emails into links, but not the "link" field. But since it's a channel preference, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you see the channel preferences for the "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links?"

Comment: This really is a valid use case that EE should support or the automatically create links/email behavior should be able to be toggled on a field by field basis.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I kind of found a solution. It looks like EE doesn't automatically turn URLs into links if they're surrounded by quotes. So I just pass 'www.test.com' instead of www.test.com in my link field and omit the quotes in the template.